# What was the first work where the main characters became the 'aliens' who crashed at Roswell?

Tags: time-travel, history-of, trope

In some science fiction works, such as Futurama's *Roswell that Ends Well* and DS9's *Little Green Men*, established characters somehow go back in time and crash-land near Roswell New Mexico, and basically end up being the 'aliens' of the Roswell incident- what work was the first to do this?

Comment: Do they get physically changed into greys?

Comment: Apart from the initial newspaper report in 1947, the wikipedia article [UFO Conspiracy Theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFO_conspiracy_theories) says the incident was mostly forgotten until around 1980, so if there are any examples before *Little Green Men* from 1995 they'd probably be in that 15-year date range.

Comment: So basically you're looking for stories told from the point of view of the space aliens who crashed their UFO near Roswell in 1947

Comment: @user14111 - I interpreted the question to be asking for stories where the main characters are time travelers who end up at Roswell, but maybe Nu'Daq can clarify if time travel is essential or not? (Also does the reference to 'established characters' require it be part of a series, or could it be a one-off story?)

Comment: @Hypnosifl- yes, time travel is part of it (why I added the time travel tag), and by established characters I meant characters who have important parts in a series or film, if not being the main characters themselves.

Comment: It’s not Roswell, but the idea of travelling back in time and causing a UFO scare is in TOS: “Tomorrow is Yesterday”. The Air Force Captain they beam aboard jokes about “Little Green Men”.